# WPF: How to use adorners for validation purposes?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, validation, adorner

**Context:**

I'm creating a Login interface using WPF 4 which consists of two `Label`s, one `TextBox` (for the username) and one `PasswordBox`. Both elements use the same style / template.

The username is bound to a `Username` property in my `User` model class, which is instantiated in the View's View-Model (which represents its `DataContext`)

The password updates the model using code-behind events (i.e.: `OnPasswordChanged`).

I also have two properties in my model which represents the valid state of my username and password, i.e.:

- `UsernameIsValid`
- `PasswordIsValid`

Those properties are updated by my View-Model and Service classes.

**Question:**

How can I create an `Adorner` for these elements' `Style` and only display it when the `UsernameIsValid` or `PasswordIsValid` properties are true ?

I'd also like, if possible, to pass in parameter the text to be displayed in the adorner (which will be a callout, which displays text, and an icon)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's late so not providing code but will give you short answer.

1. Setup Data Validation on the properties the text boxes are bound too (ValidationRule interface)
2. Set default style on text box with adorner to what it should be when valid
3. Set a style to what it should be when invalid using the DataError trigger.

Below is how you get the xaml code to flip in the style.

```
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                <Setter 
                    Property="ToolTip" 
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's appreciated. The problem here is that I would like to display the adorners in the event that the credantials provided are invalid. (i.e.: the username / password do not match an entry in the database). This means that I'm updating the UsernameIsValid and PasswordIsValid properties in my View-Model, and I'd like to display/hide the adorners on the controls depending on the value of those validation properties. (both controls use the same style) Is such a thing possible ? How can I bind an adorner to a style, and toggle it using a trigger on my validation properties ?

Comment: In that case you should setup a Trigger that is based on the value (bool / false) in the style.  Bind this to the bool value on your view model.